# Chrome reporting failed request although failure is treated in JS

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, axios

I am using `axios` to send XHRs to my server. I expect my API to return `400 Bad Request` in some case that I am treating especially:

```
axios.request({ /* ... */})
  .then(() => console.log('success'))
  .catch((e) => /* do something with the error */);
```

When the server returns indeed HTTP 400 error code, Chrome logs a failed request in the console. Why is it logged and how can I suppress this? (I don't want users to see failed requests when everything is working well).

**EDIT** This appears in the Console tab of the Developer tools.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by saying _Chrome logs a failed request in the console._ ? Do you mean the network tab ? If no, then at the code you present, you have a `catch` block where you log the output of any non sucessfull request.

Comment: @Korte not the Network tab. I said _to the console_. Literally in the Console tab.

Comment: @Korte also, the `console.log` is a bad example for the real code. I am not actually logging anything into the console in my app.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I see there is an [an open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=124534) ; I don't think there is any way to figure this out.